# Is it possible to install old versions of Raspbmc?

Tags: raspbmc

During several months the Raspbmc over my Raspberry pi worked fantastic, but with the two last updates, the raspberry have become unitilizable:

- With the update of 04/14, the ssh service was unusable and the wireless keyboard stopped to work.
- With the update of 05/5, the sound stopped to working (only whitenoise).

So, I think that maybe the best I could do is to install and old version of Raspbmc (with I was very happy) and disable the automatic updates.

Is it possible? How can I get an old version of Raspbmc?

Comment: I can't find an older version anywhere. You could try XBMC or OpenELEC instead.

Comment: You can ask the maintainer of RaspBMC, https://twitter.com/samnazarko if there are any older versions, or if he knows about this bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to download old versions.

For this concrete problem, the solution was to erase the content of the card and install the last version of raspbmc.

The bug only was present from updating, but worked ok from clean install.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible and easy, go to this [website](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org) and then click the file raspbmc then images then choose which version you wont and then choose 
raspbmc-(date).img.gz and download. you can find any version of a raspberry pi os that is shown under the 3rd party software and raspbian at raspberrypi.org download page. I used it to install the first raspbian version to see what it was like. and this is the official raspberry pi website it takes you to not some sketchy website.

Answer (score -1):

I used this website, haven't run it yet. But I will try. Hope it helps.
http://mirrors.arizona.edu/raspbmc/downloads/bin/filesystem/

Comment: This link is still working!